# OpenGL Texture Clamping

Tags: opengl

I've read the [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) on `glTeximage2D` and am a bit confused in which case OpenGL clamps the texture values to [0,1] or not. I'm using `GL_RED` as **format** in my texture and the documentation says:

> *format* determines the composition of each element in data. It can
>   assume one of these symbolic values:
>
> **GL_RED** Each element is a single red component. The GL converts it to floating point and assembles it into an RGBA element by attaching 0 for green and blue, and 1 for alpha. Each component is clamped to the range [0,1].

Doesn't this basically say that OpenGL always clamps the values regardless of the internal format?

However when I upload my texture as:

`glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R16F, width, height, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, data);`

OpenGL does **not** clamp my data with `GL_R16F` as **internal** format. But if I change the internal format to `GL_R16` they do get clamped. Where does the documentation say anything about clamping based on the **internal** format?

Comment: Sorry accidentally pasted the link to the old docs. Updated the link to point to OpenGL 4

Comment: For color component groups, if the internalformat of the texture
is signed or unsigned normalized fixed-point, components are clamped to [−1, 1]
or [0, 1], respectively. For depth component groups, the depth value is clamped
to [0, 1]. Otherwise, values are not modified. OpenGL 4.4 (Core Profile) - March 19, 2014 p183-184

Comment: So regular textures (GL_R16) store fixed-point data. GL_R16F are floating point, thus not modified

Answer (score 1):

The [OpenGL Wiki about Image Format](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format#Color_formats)
includes more information about this.

> OpenGL has a particular syntax for writing its color format enumerants. It looks like this:
>
> ```
> GL_[components​][size​][type​]
> ```
>
> - : No type suffix means unsigned normalized integer format.
> - `_SNORM`: Signed normalized integer format.
> - `F`: Floating-point. Thus, `GL_RGBA32F` is a floating-point format where each component is a 32-bit IEEE floating-point value.
> - `I`: Signed integral format. Thus `GL_RGBA8I` gives a signed integer format where each of the four components is an integer on the range `[-128, 127]`.
> - `UI`: Unsigned integral format. The values go from `[0, MAX_INT]` for the integer size.

In correlation to pixels transfers the [OpenGL Wiki about Pixel Transfer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Format_conversion)
includes that.

> When data is being transferred to an image, pixel values are converted to either floating-point or integer values. If the image format is normalized, the values that are written are clamped to [0, 1] and normalized. If the image format is integral, then the integral input values are copied verbatim.

Comment: He's talking about the [pixel transfer format](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer_Format). That's a different Wiki page.

Comment: @NicolBolas correct but under *Format conversion* it mentions that normalization is based on the image format. Thus how we end up at the other wiki page. Unless I'm mistaking?